# loop to create a dictionary, D, which looks like: {1:100, 2:99,3:98,…,100:1}

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary that comes out as {1:100, 2:99,3:98,…,100:1}

I was messing around and got this

```
D = { }
keys = range(101)
i = 0
values = [100]
for i in keys:
    for x in values:
        x = i
        D[x] = i
        pass
print D
```

this has a output of

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96, 97: 97, 98: 98, 99: 99, 100: 100}
```

so I need to find a way to inverse it and get rid of the 0, I know .reverse() wont work on a dictionary and

```
list(reversed(sorted(a.keys())))
```

just made it a list that got rid of the 1:...100:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While other answers are correct I think this is a good case for a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). It makes the code easier to read and more pythonic

```
result = { i: 101 - i for i in range(1, 101)}
```

To make it even better you can make the code reusable using a variable instead of harcoding the `101`, so:

```
num = 101
result = { i: num - i for i in range(1, num)}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
# Save the range object for efficiency
In [30]: nums = range(1, 101)

# Dict comprehension to with zip to produce the desired dict
In [31]: {f: r for f, r in zip(nums, nums[::-1])}
Out[31]: 
{1: 100,
 2: 99,
...
100: 1}

# Or use the dict constructor directly on the iterator returned by zip
In [32]: dict(zip(nums, nums[::-1]))
Out[32]: 
{1: 100,
 2: 99,
...
100: 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension with enumerate and range to create the dictionary.

```
print( {k:v for k,v in enumerate(range(100,0,-1),1)})
#{1: 100, 2: 99, 3: 98, 4: 97, 5: 96, 6: 95, 7: 94, 8: 93, 9: 92, 10: 91, 11: 90, 12: 89, 13: 88, 14: 87, 15: 86, 16: 85, 17: 84, 18: 83, 19: 82, 20: 81, 21: 80, 22: 79, 23: 78, 24: 77, 25: 76, 26: 75, 27: 74, 28: 73, 29: 72, 30: 71, 31: 70, 32: 69, 33: 68, 34: 67, 35: 66, 36: 65, 37: 64, 38: 63, 39: 62, 40: 61, 41: 60, 42: 59, 43: 58, 44: 57, 45: 56, 46: 55, 47: 54, 48: 53, 49: 52, 50: 51, 51: 50, 52: 49, 53: 48, 54: 47, 55: 46, 56: 45, 57: 44, 58: 43, 59: 42, 60: 41, 61: 40, 62: 39, 63: 38, 64: 37, 65: 36, 66: 35, 67: 34, 68: 33, 69: 32, 70: 31, 71: 30, 72: 29, 73: 28, 74: 27, 75: 26, 76: 25, 77: 24, 78: 23, 79: 22, 80: 21, 81: 20, 82: 19, 83: 18, 84: 17, 85: 16, 86: 15, 87: 14, 88: 13, 89: 12, 90: 11, 91: 10, 92: 9, 93: 8, 94: 7, 95: 6, 96: 5, 97: 4, 98: 3, 99: 2, 100: 1}
```

`Enumerate` takes a secondary optional parameter to start at that number (1 in this case) and `range` accepts 3 parameter `(start, stop, steps)`

Edit: it seems you don't need a dict comprehension like Pault pointed out:

```
dict(enumerate(range(100,0,-1),1))
```

would work.

Comment: Don't need the dict comprehension here. You can use the `dict` constructor: `dict(enumerate(range(100,0,-1),1))` directly with `enumerate`

Comment: This is the most pythonic IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Best possible answers have been given. 
If you still want a simpler approach, this helps. :)

```
D = {}
for i in range(1,101):
    D[i]=101-i
print(D)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict(zip(range(1,101),range(100,0,-1)))
```

What you are doing in this code is first generating a list with all the numbers from 1-100 `range(1,101)` and from 100-1 `range(100,0,-1)` using the range command. You set the start and end points (the final sequence does not include the end, which is why you put 101 or 0) and the spacing (-1 when counting down).

Next you make a list with these two lists zipped together `zip()` which gives you `[(1,100),(2,99),...(100,1)]`

Finally the `dict` function makes a dictionary out of this list of tuples, where the first entry is the key and the second is the value. So, your final outcome is

`{1:100, 2:99, 3:98...100:1}`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please explain your code. Try to look at it from a beginner's perspective.  Someone who can understand it without explanation could have written it themselves.